# SSRS (BIDS 2008) Deployed Report Missing Elements That Are Visible In 'Preview'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids

I have a really strange issue I can't seem to get around.  Data goes missing from a report I deploy to the report server, when it works just fine in preview on my local machine (as well as other employee's local machines).  When I run the report in Preview mode in SSRS, I get the following display, which is correct:

edit: apparently I need 10 reputation to put images in my post.  Okay, well, here are links you'll have to manually click.  Sorry.

[image]

Notice there are four rows (due to correct grouping) and a boolean value (False) displayed on each row.

When I deploy the report to the server (SQL Server 2008 R2), grouping for some reason combines the four rows into two, and the boolean values disappear:

[image]

I have deleted the report from the server, cleared my local machine cache, emptied my /bin/ folder and restored from our repository, and tried previewing the report on other colleague's machines.  It works *fine* on everyone's local machines, but the report server seems to be missing something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the report server is connecting to a different database, with different data contained therein?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add that the server and local machine are both using the same dataset to pull data from the same database, so it's not that. I appreciate the reply though!

Comment: DataSET != DataSOURCE

Comment: DataSOURCE is the same as well.

Comment: If you export the report to a data-only format, like XML or CSV, what do you see in those fields?

Comment: The data is missing when exported into any format from the report server. It's there when exported into any format from Preview.

Comment: Prime suspect is a Cached Copy of this report. If this isn't a cached report then look into Data Source and then finally check your dataset query. I cant think of anything else causing this issue.

Comment: I got it figured out.  I can't answer my own question for another six hours or so (maybe a mod can update this with the solution?):

I was using shared dataset that called a proc.  I updated the proc and refreshed the dataset in SSRS, which allowed me to see the new fields I had added.

However, when deploying this new dataset to the server (even with _Overwrite Datasets_ set to _True_), the server didn't recognize that the fields had changed - because the proc was the same - and never updated the dataset on the server.  

I deleted the dataset from the server and redeployed; all is well now.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your page layout of preview. I red hilite page layout on following image.

[image]

Perhaps don't visible some item in your report preview, but sure that all item will be visible in printed page.

Comment: Not all items are visible with this issue I was dealing with, regardless of page layout in preview.  I have solved the issue - see above.  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it -

I was using a shared dataset that called a proc.  I had updated the proc to add those boolean fields, and refreshed the dataset in SSRS to work with them on the report.  Even though *OVERWRITE DATASETS* was set to *TRUE*, the server thought the shared dataset was the same (because it is still calling the same proc).  So the actual dataset on the server was never getting overwritten (this is the only logical explanation I can think of).

I deleted the dataset from the server and redeployed it, and imagine that, it works great.

Thanks for the help everyone.